# What is the maximum size of a PUT request for google app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

I've googled around, but found no answer. What is the maximum size of a PUT request for google app engine?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The maximum request size for any app engine request is 32 MB. You can see this in the [Request Quotas](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#Requests) section in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here. It explains the limit's on your application Quota

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/overview#Quotas_and_Limits

Comment: You should include the result in your answer, too, not just a link, so if the link breaks, it's still valuable.

Comment: @JesseRusak but what if that changes in the future?

Comment: Yeah, that's a good point. Usually, someone notices by following the link and then edits the answer with the new value.